# EXCEL: If cell x exists in column A then print row 2

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm currently looking at a set of data like this:

[image]

What I want is: If I enter something into G22 that exists in row A I want G25-G35 to show the content of 2A-2K respectively, else say blabla. I have a huge a** like 1000x50 excel sheet and want to be able to basically search for 1 value in column A and get all the data in its corresponding row in a new neat overview tab that isn't bloated with 5 bajillion entries.

Anyone know how to go about this in excel?

Comment: Welcome. This question does not appear to be about web applications within the scope defined in the [help center](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Please do read about the [`microsoft-excel`](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/microsoft-excel) tag

Answer (score 0):

To get result use following [ARRAY formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-an-array-formula-e43e12e0-afc6-4a12-bc7f-48361075954d) in cell G24

```
=IFERROR(TRANSPOSE(INDIRECT("A"&MATCH($G$22,$A:$A,0)&":K"&MATCH($G$22,$A:$A,0))),"No data")
```

where "A" and ":K" are your data first and last columns, so you can fit it your needs.